# view an image on PHP webpage

Tags: php, html

I want to view an image on my `PHP` webpage. Is there any way to view images on a php page ?

here is my code

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "", "");  // Establishing Connection with Server
$db = mysql_select_db("wikkolk_wikko", $connection); // Selecting Database from 

$name1 = $_GET['name'];
$sql = "select * from asd where ccc like '$name1%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
   printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]); 
   ?>
   <img src=$row[5]/>
   <?php 
   echo "<br>";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: Try using `<img src="<?=$row[5]?>"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by writting your while loop as:

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]); 
    echo '<img src="'.$row[5].'" alt="image"/>';
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: needs to be html escaped. a file or folder with `"` in the name would break it (which is legal in NTFS and ext4, to mention a few) - `echo '<img src="'.htmlentities ( $row[5], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true ).'" alt="image"/>';`